How to get RREF with LAPACK or similar library?
I want to do what Gauss-Jordan elimination does but with a few thousand rows or columns. I've heard you should use LU decomposition instead but that leaves you with trapezoidal and triangular factors which still have to be converted to reduced row echelon form. Is there a common library function for this that saves writing a lot of number crunching code myself? LAPACK has DGETRS to do forward and backward substitution but I don't want to actually solve it, and can't because there's no unique solution.
The matrix already has non-zeros on the diagonal of the left-hand square submatrix in case that can be exploited to make anything easier. Something like this
[# 0 0 0 # # # 0 0]
[0 # 0 0 # # # 0 0]
[0 # # 0 0 0 # # #]
[0 # 0 # 0 # # # #]


Given that matlab implements this from scratch, I suspect that the answer is no

What exactly are you planning on doing once you have the rref? Maybe there's another avenue. For instance, you could probably do whatever you're trying to accomplish using the SVD

Based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48447318/1318499
Write the original matrix as
$A = [A_1 | A_2]$
where $A_1$ is the left square of $A$.
The reduced row echelon form of $A$ is
$[A_1^{-1}A_1 | A_1^{-1}A_2]$
$=[I|A_1^{-1}A_2]$
$A_1^{-1}A_2$ is the solution to $A_1 x = A_2$ which can be obtained using any old multi-RHS solver such as an LU decomposition based one.
